# What is returned when passing null to CreateCompatibleDC() in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

When you call `CreateCompatibleDC(NULL)`, you get a handle to the application's current screen, as explained on MSDN:

> If this handle is NULL, the function creates a memory DC compatible with the application's current screen

I'm trying to figure out what it means by "application's current screen"?

The way I see it, it can be a handle to the current active screen, or a handle that encompass all the visible parts of the application.

Say I have a window and a modal child window (pop up window), will I get a DC to only the modal child or to the full visible area?

Comment: CCDC creates a *memory* context.  Nothing to do with "current active screen" or "all visible parts".  Its pixel format is compatible with the current screen, 32bpp on all modern machines, so that whatever you do with it later will blit to the screen as fast as possible.

Comment: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html

Comment: Use `GetDC` if you need the device context of a particular window.

Comment: @Hans - tnx, I miss understood compatible to say same size, after reading your comment it now looks pretty Straightforward- guess its time to call it a day:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: a handle to a Memory DC.

More specifically: `CreateCompatibleDC(NULL)` returns a handle to a memory device context whose format is same as the device context that would be returned by `GetDC(NULL)`.  But it is not the same context.  Drawing to it doesn't actually show anything on the screen.

Memory DCs are usually used to for things like creating bitmaps in memory.